# How to get Jwt token Claim from a blazor page?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, blazor

I've built and application which uses JWT authentication. When creating a profile page for a customer I want to get relative information of the customer such as: First Name, Last Name, credits etc.

I found that by using `@context.User.FindFirst("FirstName")` inside a .razor page I can get the values from the token BUT on the web page it shows in this format `FirstName:Bob`, when I just want to get the name `Bob`.

**How can I get the values from a token in a more elegant/eficient way?**

Something similar like we would use for `@context.User.Identity.Name`

**Generate Claims Method:**

```
private List<Claim> GenerateClaims(Shared.Models.User user)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, config["Jwt:Subject"]),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.userName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.type),
        new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName),
        new Claim("LastName", user.LastName),
        new Claim("Credits", user.Credits.ToString())
    };
    return claims.ToList();
}
```

As you see from the method above, I want to get all the `new Claim("Example", user.Example)`

Comment: `@context.User.FindFirst("FirstName")?.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtension
{
    public static string GetClaimValue(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, string type)
        => claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(type)?.Value ?? string.Empty;
}
```

#### usage

```
@context.User.GetClaimValue("FirstName")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to change it a bit in order to meet my requirements, I've put this method locally into my blazor page, and I'm getting the current Authorized user by using `public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthState { get; set; } = null!;`. Not sure if it your method was intended to be used this way but hey, it works)